# Check fn key is depressed

Tags: python, macos, cocoa

Is there a way for me to check that the <kbd>fn</kbd> (MacBook Pro) key is being depressed?

I tried already:

```
Cocoa.NSEvent.modifierFlags()
```

which returns `8388608` when the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is pressed, but it also returns the same when any of the function keys are pressed, so I can't tell the difference between <kbd>fn</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, etc.

Is there a way for me to check that the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is being depressed? (Note that I don't care if other keys are simultaneously depressed, it should just return true as long as the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is regardless of the states of other keys.)

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516031/macos-is-it-possible-to-detect-when-the-fn-key-is-pressed-on-a-mac-keyboard

Comment: @RolfofSaxony no, saw it already but don't know how python's cocoa allows you to get those props

Comment: Have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput It helped this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987661/how-to-use-mac-os-x-nsevents-within-wxpython-application

Comment: @RolfofSaxony is there a way for me to check with pynput whether a key is held down even before the program has started?

Comment: Suck it and see, I guess, I have no idea, I've never personally used it.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony that's what I've been trying for the past 40 mins